# Apply Low Pass Filter

Tags: java, android

How to apply this Low Pass Filter Function in my code:

```
static final float alpha = 0.05f;
    public float[] lowPass(float[] output, float[] input)
    {
        output[0] = output[0] + alpha * (input[0] - output[0]);
        output[1] = output[1] + alpha * (input[1] - output[1]);
        output[2] = output[2] + alpha * (input[2] - output[2]);
        return output;
    }
```

***Reading Accelerometer and detecting an accident*** 
I Want mLastX, mLastY and mLastZ save  accelerometer readings after being filtered with low pass filter

```
public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values)
    {
        if (sensor != SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) return;
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if ((now - mLastForce) > SHAKE_TIMEOUT) {
            mShakeCount = 0;
        }

        if ((now - mLastTime) > TIME_THRESHOLD) {
            long diff = now - mLastTime;
            float speed = Math.abs(values[SensorManager.DATA_X] + values[SensorManager.DATA_Y] + values[SensorManager.DATA_Z] - mLastX - mLastY - mLastZ) / diff * 10000;
            if (speed > FORCE_THRESHOLD) {
                if ((++mShakeCount >= SHAKE_COUNT) && (now - mLastShake > SHAKE_DURATION)) {
                    mLastShake = now;
                    mShakeCount = 0;
                    if (mShakeListener != null) {
                        mShakeListener.onShake();
                    }
                }
                mLastForce = now;
            }
            mLastTime = now;
            mLastX = values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
            mLastY = values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
            mLastZ = values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it with the first parameter initially being the array [mlastx, mlastY, mlastz] and the second parameter being the current values of the sensor.  After being called, the values of the first array will be changed and should become mlastX, mlastY, and mlastZ.  Its actually easier to code if you just keep them as an array rather than holding them in separate variables.

Now wether this will accomplish what you want is another question.  Your math as it is in that function has some odd things in it, and a few things just outright wrong.  For example, you're summing accelerations and dividing by time to get a "speed".  No, that gets you jerk.  Speed would require you to multiply by time.  And to get a true vector magnitude you should be adding the squares of the speed differences for each component, not the absolute values.  THe 10K multiplication makes no sense, just divide the threshold by 10K, as its unlikely to be used anywhere else.  This has a feeling of someone who tried to translate an algorithm they didn't really understand.